# Overvoltage protection develops heat, is ok?

Tags: circuit-design, components, circuit-protection

considering my old question: [Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/540423/how-does-this-overvoltage-protection-work), i've made the following circuit using equivalent components on SMD, here is the schematic:

[image: sch]

And these are the parts that i've picked from LCSC:

- Fuse: [Link here](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/PTC-Resettable-Fuses_TECHFUSE-mSMD110-16V_C69691.html)
- Zener diode: [Link here](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Zener-Diodes_Shandong-Jingdao-Microelectronics-MM1W5V1_C382836.html)
- Resistor: [Link here](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Chip-Resistor-Surface-Mount_UNI-ROYAL-Uniroyal-Elec-25121WF1001T4E_C54315.html)
- Transistor: [Link here](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Transistors-NPN-PNP_Nexperia-BCP56-115_C22239.html)

The circuit is receiving 5.1V from the +5V netflag (using a regulated DC power supply) and giving out 4.93V from the netflag +5V-OUT (the circuit on the +5V-OUT draw a really low current: 250mA), everything works good, but the transistor itself (on the backside) develops a lot of heat (65/68°C at 21°C room temperature).

Is that normal?
I need to be worried?

Comment: Check drop voltage on resistor.

Comment: What happens if you reduce the resistor value to eg. 680 ohms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zenner diode should be choosen the bigger voltage value. It is not ideal device and some current runs then voltage is close to nominal. It cause drop voltage on resistor. Even it is around 0.3-0.5V transistor in active mode.

Comment: So, in active mode...and then some current flows through the transistor...how much?

Comment: Transistor datasheet, fig.17.  Measure drop voltage on resistor.

Comment: The voltage drop on the resistor is 0.6V

Comment: According to graf it is 1 mA with 25 °C ambient. Senna and resistor  has 0.6 mA. You can measure real current without load, minus 0.6 mA you will get Ic transistors current. Wattage 5V• Ic. Heat pad under transistor needed.

Comment: But your scheme may not be good. In case of overvoltage if transistor burns before the PTC fuse restrrict current, it will not protect your circuit. Should better dissipate heat. Old school solution is melting fuse and big zenner diode. Overvoltage and reversed polarity protection. Zenner should be 5.6V.